# Ubuntu 16.04 cant boot with kernel 4.4, only with kernel 3.13, dell inspiron 14

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel, dell

I have a Dell Inspiron 14 5000, it comes natively with Ubuntu 14.10, no dual boot.

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04, and it can't boot, it lands on a blank screen with the caps lock key blinking.

I managed to fix this by reverting to kernel 3.13 and I can run it normally this way, but if I upgrade it to 4.4 it reverts to the no boot/blinking caps lock error again.

After a lot of research I've given up trying to get it running 16.04 with the correct kernel on my own... any ideas?

Comment: Does it have AMD/ATI graphics card ? If so then this may be the problem.

Comment: Hello Harris, the graphic card is Intel® HD Graphics 5500, I understand is integrated with the processor. I seen on a lot of foruns some comments about the graphic card not being supported by the kernel, but it doenst appear to be the case.

Comment: try to boot without splash and quite parameters.  on grub chose your kernel, press e, remove them and boot, check the on screen logs

Comment: Artyom, I did. Its a disaster, actually :-). The only screen log is "loading Linux 4.4.0-31-generic" and nothing else, just blank and a constantly blinking caps lock. I think the next line would be "load video", so it appears to be video related, but I have no idea how to fix it...